# Java Date format weird

Tags: java, date

I have an issue where I would like to get the start of the day, however it seems to be setting it to 12:00 via automatic.

```
SimpleDateFormat dfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String todayDate = dfFull.parse("2014-06-06 00:00:00");

today = dfFull.format(todayDate);
System.out.println(today);
```

Why is this spitting out:

```
2014-06-06 12:00:00
```

The `12:00:00` is the issue

Comment: "hh" means hour in am/pm, but you aren't specifying am/pm. Try using "HH", which means hours in 24 hour format.

Comment: There is no zero-hour in 12-hour format...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because `hh` represents the hour in 12 hour format. You need to use `HH` instead.

```
SimpleDateFormat dfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

Also, on a side note, there is a typo in your code.

```
SimpleDateFormat dfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date todayDate = dfFull.parse("2014-06-06 00:00:00"); // todayDate must be of type Date and not String
String today = dfFull.format(todayDate); // today should be of type String
System.out.println(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `HH` for hours in this case.

```
SimpleDateFormat dfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String todayDate = dfFull.parse("2014-06-06 00:00:00");

today = dfFull.format(todayDate);
System.out.println(today);
```

Now you will get the out put as

```
2014-06-06 00:00:00
```

And again if you use `hh` that mean you are using 12 hour format while `HH` means 24 hour format

So